# How to define variable expression for Enumerable.Where

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say I created list

```
var firstList = new List<>(new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6});
```

And want to return only even numbers, but expression should passed as a variable

```
var secondList = firstList.Where(myExpression).ToList();
```

I don't know what to assign to `myExpression` to achieve this.

```
Expression<Func<int, bool>> myExpression = ?
```

Can you give some advice?

Comment: `Expression<Func<int, bool>> myExpression = n => n % 2 == 0;`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of messing with expressions, you can use delegates:

```
Func<int, bool> test = w => w % 2 == 0;
var secondList = firstList.Where(test).ToList();
```

Comment: Isn't that essentially work the same way as @syyyl 's answer? It just uses delegates instead of expressions, but doesn't change much

Comment: Yes you are right but i'm preparing it for entity that's why i test expression instead   single delegate function. Anyway thank you:)